# Can't get WMI namespace RSOP to work

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I need to create a subroutine to check for certain policies on a system. I'm currently just trying to do that.

strComputerFQDN is defined at the beginning of the program and that is working fine.

Do you see anything wrong?

Here is my code:

```
'*************************************************************************
' This Subroutine checks Local Policies
'*************************************************************************
Sub CheckPolicies()
   Dim objGPOSrvc,colItems,objItem
   Set objGPOSrvc = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputerFQDN & "\root\RSOP")
   Set colItems = objGPOSrvc.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM RSOP_GPO")

   WScript.Echo("Check Policies")
   WScript.Echo("------------------------------------")

   For Each objItem in colItems
      If InStr(UCase(objItem.Name),"WSUS") Then
         If InStr(UCase(objItem.Name),"SERVER") Then
            WScript.Echo("Policy applied: " & objItem.Name)
         Else
            WScript.Echo("Wrong WSUS Policy Applied - Check Computer object location")
         End If
      End If
   Next
   If strWSUSApplied = "FALSE" Then
      WScript.Echo("No WSUS Policy Applied!")
   End If
   WScript.Echo vbCrLf
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace should be `root\RSOP\Computer`

```
Set objGPOSrvc = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputerFQDN & "\root\RSOP\Computer")
```

or `root\RSOP\User`

```
Set objGPOSrvc = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputerFQDN & "\root\RSOP\User")
```

Most typically you would do something like this:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\RSOP\Computer")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from RSOP_GPO")
For Each objItem in colItems  
    WScript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
    WScript.Echo "GUID Name: " & objItem.GUIDName
    WScript.Echo "ID: " & objItem.ID
    WScript.Echo "Access Denied: " & objItem.AccessDenied
    WScript.Echo "Enabled: " & objItem.Enabled
    WScript.Echo "File System path: " & objItem.FileSystemPath
    WScript.Echo "Filter Allowed: " & objItem.FilterAllowed
    WScript.Echo "Filter ID: " & objItem.FilterId
    WScript.Echo "Version: " & objItem.Version
    WScript.Echo
Next
```

If you receive Error 0x80041003, you will need to run this script with administrator credentials.  For Vista and later, open your start menu and type `cmd`.  When "Command Prompt" appears, right-click and choose Run As Administrator.  You can now launch your script from the elevated command prompt without error.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I changed it to match your code but I am getting this error. (null): 0x80041003, this is the line where "Set objWMIService" is.

Comment: You will need to run this script with administrator credentials, please see my edit.